# What do you call the back section of a plane?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the back section of a plane? Usually, the front section is the first class, I am not sure if it has another name, and the back section I have no idea what it's called. Is it called the economy class section? I never boarded a plane, so I am not sure what it's called. I am talking about the section where you can sit as a passenger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The back section of the plane is called the rear of the plane (or tail section), but if you are talking about the section where the non-first-class fliers sit, there are several names for that, including *economy class*,  *main cabin*, and *coach*.

It can be a little confusing, because an airplane may only have four rows of first-class seats, meaning that everything from Row 5 to the last row of the plane might all be designated as coach seating, even though Row 5 is much closer to the front of the plane than the rear.

One [travel website](https://www.cheapflights.com/news/what-are-airline-classes) explains it this way:

> Whether you call it coach, standard, main cabin, or “cattle class,” **economy** is the most basic class. The slightly comfier **premium economy** offers wider seats and more legroom at a comfier price than business or first class on most airlines. Some airlines categorize economy and premium economy under **main cabin**.

Answer (score 0):

In English its normally known as the economy cabin.